# What sort of binary representation is %xA and such?

Tags: websocket, binary, hex, standards

I'm setting up a websocket server to connect with a web browser, while reading the [Specification (RFC 6455)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) for websocket frame exchange I came across these values that are supposed to represent a 4bit op code, they look like this:

%x0 %x1 %x2 ..... %xA %xB .... %xF

I know that %x0 = 0000 and %x1 = 0001

I'd like to know what these values are called and how to convert them to bits.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `%xN` representations use a single hexadecimal digit to describe a four-bit binary number.

The possible values of a four-bit binary number range from 0 (`0000`) to 15 (`1111`), so each value can be expressed as a hexadecimal digit:

```
     0  %x0
     1  %x1
    10  %x2
    11  %x3
   100  %x4
   101  %x5
   110  %x6
   111  %x7
  1000  %x8
  1001  %x9
  1010  %xA
  1011  %xB
  1100  %xC
  1101  %xD
  1110  %xE
  1111  %xF
```